# R: Reference list item within the same list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, assignment-operator, tibble

In R, we can reference items created within that same list, i.e.:

`list(a = a <- 1, b = a)`

I am curious if there is a way to write a function which takes the place of `a = a <- 1`. That is, if something like

```
`%=%` <- function(x,y) {
  envir <- environment()
  char_x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  assign(char_x, y, parent.env(envir))
  unlist(lapply(setNames(seq_along(x),char_x), function(T) y))
}
# does not work
list(a%=%1, b=a)
```

is possible in R (i.e. returns the list given above)?

edit: I think this boils down to asking, 'can we call list with a language object that preserves all aspects of manually coding list?' (specifically, assigns the list's names attribute the left-hand side of the language element).

It seems to me that below shows that such a solution is hopeless.

```
my_call <- do.call(substitute, list(expr(expr = {x = y}), list(x=quote(a), y=1)))
equals <- languageEl(my_call, which = 1)
str(equals)
do.call(list, list(equals))
```

Comment: After entering your function above: `> class(%=%)
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "class(%=%"
> class(`%=%`)
[1] "function"`, so perhaps the `ticks` matter in the call. Well, not. `> list( a`%=%`1, b = a)
Error: unexpected symbol in "list( a`%=%`"`. But then again, as an assignment `> whatever <- list( a %=% 1, b = a)
> str(whatever)
List of 2
 $  : Named num 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
 $ b: num 1`.  From which I suggest that you haven't established a print method upon your function `%=%` operator, or something like that. Which might become the better question.

Comment: Actually lexical scoping, not print method. So we see, under assignment, your function works.

Comment: @Chris thanks for commenting. I'm not quite sure what you mean. The function does not return the same list:
`identical(list(a%=%1, b=a),list(a=a <- 1, b=a))` returns FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, the clever folk behind `tibble` have figured this out in their `lst()` function (also in package `dplyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
lst(a=1, b=a, c=c(3,4), d=c)
```

What a useful feature!